# Cannot access a value stored in a hidden field from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hiddenfield

I have a Sales Order ID which I need as a SelectParameter for my GridView of products ordered, so I am storing it in a hidden field (outside the GridView).  On the same page, I'm adding products to this order then I rebind the GridView to include that product.  The value of my parameter each time is null so I don't think it's getting the value from the hidden field.  I thought of storing it in ViewState but don't think you can retrieve a ViewState value from a GridView SelectParameter or can you? Anyway, if someone can tell me why using a hiddenfield value outside of the GridView won't work (it's still in the form), that would be fab! Also, I'd like an option to use ViewState so would need to know what my SelectParameter code would be.  Code as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hSOId" runat="server" />
<div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <strong>Products:</strong>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvOptions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="10" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" EmptyDataText="No Products Added" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Internal_Name" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="Internal_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="Qty" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total_Kilo_Weight" HeaderText="Weight" SortExpression="Total_Kilo_Weight" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sales_Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Sales_Price" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProfitMargin" HeaderText="Profit" SortExpression="ProfitMargin" />               
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Co_Depot" HeaderText="Depot" SortExpression="Co_Depot" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pack_Date" HeaderText="Pack Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" SortExpression="Pack_Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Delivery_Date" HeaderText="Delivery Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" SortExpression="Delivery_Date" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConn %>" 
        SelectCommand="spSalesOrderProductsRead" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" OnSelecting="gvOptions_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="hSOId" Name="SalesOrderID"     Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div><!-- end of column -->
    </div><!-- end of row -->
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Consider including code, no one wants to read para and answer in para

Comment: very poor info. Please add more details and source code

Comment: I know but this is my first post with code and it's saying indent by 4 lines so this will take me a while - argghh!  Doing it now :-)

Comment: The "brackets" button in the editor can indent the text for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot do this within HTML code, but just the code behind (C# or VB) - or at least outside .

See this to how get HiddenField info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks - I can set and retrieve the values of my hidden field from my code behind, but the parameter is showing null for the value when I debug it using code to determine the value in the OnSelecting method of my datasource so that's why I think maybe GridView doesn't like HiddenField values as parameters.  I've googled and cannot find anything on this though.

Comment: If your value is returning null is not related to GridView or HiddenFields. The problem may be related to the Event you´re focusing (OnSelecting). Try to see if you have another event (like OnDataPropertyChanged or OnSelectedIndexChanged). See also TrackViewState here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Gone back to the old-fashioned way and it works!  I saved the Sales Order ID in a View State object then retrieved it when I wanted to rebind and it works perfectly.  Would still like to know if there is a way just to call gvOptions.Bind(); and somehow get the SelectParameter to retrieve the View State value - I'm sure there must be a way.  Anyway, feeling happy now and hope this may help others:

```
  protected void rebindGVProducts()
  {
    string strError = "";
    int soID = 0;

    if(ViewState["SOID"] != null)
        soID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["SOID"]);
    //hSOId.Value = soID;

    try
    {
        //Get all Products in this sales order
        ConnectionStringSettings SHConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"];
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(SHConn.ConnectionString);
        //SqlDataReader objRdr;
        SqlCommand objCmd;

        objConn.Open();
        objCmd = new SqlCommand("spSalesOrderProductsRead", objConn);
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesOrderID", soID);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "Products");

        gvProducts.DataSource = ds;
        gvProducts.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
        gvProducts.DataBind();

        //objRdr.Close();
        objConn.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException objSqlDbException)
    {
        foreach (SqlError objError in objSqlDbException.Errors)
        {
            //Response.Write("Error is: "+objError);
            strError += objError;
        }
        //add errors to error log file ErrorLogFile.txt
        reportError(strError);

        Response.Write("Sorry - we are currenly experiencing problems with our database, please try again later.");
    }
}
```